# Is it possible to convert any relational algebra expression into a relational calculus expression?

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra, relational-calculus

Let's for the sake of simplicity only focus on tuple relational calculus.

Every relational algebra query can be broken down into the 5 atomic operations - projection, selection, set union, set difference, cartesian product (I'm excluding renaming as it is not possible to do in relational calculus).

Let $P(x)$ be an arbitrary predicate and $r$, $s$ relations with attributes $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ respectively.

For the 5 atomic operations, we have a conversion:
$\newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}$
\begin{align}
    \Pi_{a_{1},\dots,a_{n}}(r) &\iff \Set{t}{\exists p \in r \left(\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t.a_i = p.a_i \right)}, \\
    \sigma_{P(x)}(r) &\iff \Set{t}{t \in r \land P(x)},\\
    r \cup s &\iff \Set{t}{t \in r \lor t \in s}, \\
    r \setminus s &\iff \Set{t}{t \in r \land t \notin s}, \\
    r \times s &\iff \Set{t}{\exists p \in r \; \exists q \in s \left( \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t.a_i = p.a_i  \land \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t.b_i = p.b_i \right)}. 
\end{align}

But we only used $r$ and $s$ which are relations. What if we have an expression in a form of $Q_{1} \bigoplus Q_{2}$ where $Q_1$, $Q_2$ are also queries?

Is it possible to write a general formula for the 5 main operations while only using the most general $Q_1$, $Q_2$?

Comment: You need to clearly distinguish between relation values vs relation programming/DB variable names vs logic variables vs query expressions, for both algebra & calculus. That includes dealing properly with what attributes a relation/tuple value or programming or logic variable involving some has. Also &\iff is not appropriate, figure out what exact statement you want to make about what things. This applies to both whatever you think you've said formally now & your final mapping. PS Please put your question in your post body, not just the title. PS Mapping calculus to algebra [sic] is harder.

Comment: There are many versions of relational algebra & tuple (& domain) relational calculi. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give definitions & a reference (textbook name, edition & page) for yours. (It wouldn't matter so much if you were *defining* some calculus queries in terms of algebra queries but here we don't know whether you are using a given calculus correctly.)

Comment: Different versions? Where did you see that? I clearly stated the 5 atomic operations and their counterparts. Is the definiton of a relation relevant? I'm not really sure how to respond to that.  I'm just trying to find out how to connect the two languages when there are nested queries in the epxressions. If you have some references to different version of relational algebra and relational calculus, please show me so I can restate my question more clearly. I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Just about any collection of presentations of algebras or of calculi will differ. Dozens of textbooks are free online in pdf & html. (But typically presentations are poor.) But what is stopping you from quoting/summarizing the reference you are using? If you can't give your definitions, how do you expect to map between expressions?--Rhetorical. Re mapping: Map an algebra query that is just a DB variable name, then map expressions referencing just 1 operator. But as I said you need to be clearer re what you are dealing with. (Eg it's not even clear what you think the line re union is saying.)

Comment: Ok. I can't send you my sources since you don't understand Czech. I looked into wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_relational_calculus and they're using identical definitions and operators as we do. Or I can come later and construct a full grammar if that's what is needed. I really can't find any good source for the definition as it is ambiguous everywhere.

Comment: The wiki algebra article is not sufficiently clear. It doesn't even define what a relation (value) is. It confuses languages with algebras--what is the type of the formula argument to its restriction?--Rhetorical. The calculus article seems OK. It makes all the kinds of distinctions I mentioned in my 1st comment re being clear re what things you are talking about & what you say about them. Notice that the articles use different notions of tuple & relation (values). And hence I doubt "using identical definitions and operators". PS Give the minimal quotes/summaries you need to ask your question.